# Bootstrapping Spark 3.0.0 on EMR cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, installation, pyspark, amazon-emr, spark3

A few days back Spark 3.0.0 was launched. I would like to use some of these functionalities. The default version for Spark on an EMR cluster now is Spark 2.4.5. I specifically make use of PySpark. My question is: how can I install/bootstrap Spark 3.0.0 on an EMR cluster?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You wait for EMR to support it, or you run spark outside of EMR.

Comment: Alright that's unfortunate. I will wait then. Thanks for the comments!

Comment: This is not just installing spark. There will be lot of compatibility issues. Setting configuration will be also a tough job.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to wait for Spark 3 to be available on EMR.  Judging by past releases you're probably looking at 1 - 3 months